# Installing cmake3.9 in ubuntu18.04

Tags: cmake

How to install cmake 3.9 or higher version in Ubuntu 18.04? I am using:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

And then trying to check version using:

```
cmake --version
```

All I am getting is:

```
cmake version 3.5.0-rc2
CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

Can you please help me to install said version of cmake?

Comment: You may have to build from source!

Comment: My own just installed version is `3.10.*` and my system is bionic!

Answer (score 0):

You can download CMake v3.9.0 for 64-bit Linux from [here](https://cmake.org/files/v3.9/cmake-3.9.0-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz) (WARNING: direct link). After downloading, open up the folder containing the download in a Terminal, and run the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
$ tar xvzf cmake-3.9.0-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz
$ cd cmake-3.9.0
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

This would install cmake to `/usr/local/bin`. You can invoke it as `/usr/local/bin/cmake`.

Let me know if I made any mistakes.

Comment: After using command                                                                                                ```tar xvzf cmake-3.9.0-Linux-x86_64.tar.gz```,                                                                             a directory named **cmake-3.9.0-Linux-x86_64** is created.                               Then I used, ```cd cmake-3.9.0-Linux-x86_64``` But  ```./configure``` returns results     ```bash: ./configure: No such file or directory```. Actually the directories inside  **cmake-3.9.0-Linux-x86_64** are ```bin  doc  man  share```

Comment: You downloaded a binary version of the package. Please locate and download a source distribution of the package, and proceed with `./configure` and the other steps.